# json_decode can't decode JSON string

Tags: php, json

I have a gzipped base64 JSON string, after converting this string json_decode() can't decode it. I think it is an encoding issue, but have been unable to resolve it.

I am running PHP 5.2 which doesn't support json_last_error().

Does anyone know what is going on here?

```
<?php 
$gzipped_base64 = "7b0HYBxJliUmL23Ke39K9UrX4HShCIBgEyTYkEAQ7MGIzeaS7B1pRyMpqyqBymVWZV1mFkDM7Z28995777333nvvvfe6O51OJ/ff/z9cZmQBbPbOStrJniGAqsgfP358Hz8ifvGv8dGv8frXaH+N7NeY/hpvf40vf43LXyP/Nepf4/zXKH+N6te4ou8e0f9f0e/4tqHff8mv8f8A";

$json = gzinflate(base64_decode($gzipped_base64));

echo $json; // prints: {"StackOverflow":"Rocks"}

$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo var_dump($array); // prints: NULL
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't `var_dump` automatically `echo`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) expects the input to be UTF-8 encoded but your data seems to be encoded with UTF-16:

```
var_export($json);
```

The output is:

```
'{' . "\0" . '"' . "\0" . 'S' . "\0" . 't' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'c' . "\0" . 'k' . "\0" . 'O' . "\0" . 'v' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . 'r' . "\0" . 'f' . "\0" . 'l' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 'w' . "\0" . '"' . "\0" . ':' . "\0" . '"' . "\0" . 'R' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 'c' . "\0" . 'k' . "\0" . 's' . "\0" . '"' . "\0" . '}' . "\0" . ''
```

So convert the character encoding using [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) to convert to UTF-8 before calling `json_decode`.

Comment: C# .NET (where my zipped string comes from) strings are UTF-16 I found out. This seems to produce garbage: mb_convert_encoding($json, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')... any thoughts?

Comment: @koen: If your output encoding is actually UTF-16, you need to convert it back to UTF-16: `mb_convert_encoding(json_decode(mb_convert_encoding($json, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16'), true), 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: @koen: Those strings might not be UTF-16 actually. At least they lack an explicit BOM, which is why mb_ confuses the endianess. Better play it safe and try `mb_convert_encoding($json, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE')`

Answer (score 1):

There are a load of unrecognized characters in-between the inflated string - so it reads `{?"?S?t?` etc...